# CDate type mismatch error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to convert a text field into a date using CDate() in a recordset but keep getting a type mismatch error. The input text format is MMDDYYYY. Does CDate not recognize this format? Do I need a separate function? Any ideas?

```
Text Date  -> Converted Date
---------     --------------
04122012   -> 04/12/2012


Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("tbl_dates", Type:=dbOpenDynaset)

Do Until rst.EOF
rst.Edit
rst![Converted Date]=CDate(rst![Text Date])
rst.Update
rst.MoveNext

Loop

Set rst = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`CDate()` won't accept your date string without some type of delimiter between the month, day, and year parts.  This attempt fails with a type mismatch error.

```
? CDate("04122012")
```

If it's helpful, you can use the `IsDate()` function to check whether your date strings are in a format `CDate()` will accept.

```
? IsDate("04122012")
False
? IsDate("04-12-2012")
True
? IsDate("04/12/2012")
True
? CDate("04-12-2012")
4/12/2012
bar = "04122012" : Debug.Print CDate(Left(bar,2) & "-" & _
    Mid(bar,3,2) & "-" & Right(bar,4))
4/12/2012
```

**Edit**: If there is a mismatch between your system's locale setting and the format of your date strings, you can transform those date strings to *yyyy-mm-dd* format to avoid problems with `CDate()`.

```
bar = "04122012" : Debug.Print CDate(Right(bar,4) & "-" & _
    Left(bar,2) & "-" & Mid(bar,3,2))
4/12/2012
```

Comment: Thanks @HansUp, I thought I must have been doing something stupid!

Answer (score 6):

The help for `CDate` says:

> CDate recognizes date formats according to the locale setting of your system. The correct order of day, month, and year may not be determined if it is provided in a format other than one of the recognized date settings.

To avoid potential confusion due to locale settings, you might use `DateSerial` instead of `CDate`, as in expression like this (assuming `Text Date` always has 8 characters in MMDDYYYY format):

```
DateSerial(Right(rst![Text Date], 4), Left(rst![Text Date], 2), Mid(rst![Text Date], 3, 2))
```