# MS Access: convert seperate year, day_count and time fields to a date/time

Tags: ms-access, datetime

I have a text file created by another program that I have imported into MS Access 2003.
The date & time fields are split into 3 seperate fields and I would like to create 1 date/time field. Here is an example of the data:

```
YEAR,DAY_NUMBER,TIME
2002,231,223405
2004,117,000000
```

YEAR: The year in YYYY format

DAY: The day of the year. e.g. 001 would represent 1st of January; 034 would be the 3rd of February

TIME: The time in HHMMSS

How do I create an additional field with the corresponding date/time value?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example assumes your table is named `MyTable`, its `YEAR` and `DAY_NUMBER` fields are both numeric data types, the `TIME` field is text, and you added a Date/Time field called `date_time`.

Try an update query with the `DateSerial()` and `TimeSerial()` functions.

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET date_time = DateSerial([YEAR],1,DAY_NUMBER)
    + TimeSerial(Left([TIME],2), Mid([TIME],3,2), Right([TIME],2));
```

**Edit**:  If I misunderstood your intention, and you don't actually need or want to store the Date/Time value, you can just derive it when needed with a `SELECT` query.

```
SELECT
    DateSerial([YEAR],1,DAY_NUMBER)
        + TimeSerial(Left([TIME],2), Mid([TIME],3,2), Right([TIME],2))
        AS date_time
FROM MyTable;
```

Comment: +1 I had no idea you could use 1 for the month and then just use > 31 in the day part. That is genius ^_^

Comment: @MattDonnan In another question recently, you and Brian Camire motivated me to take another look at `DateSerial()`.  I was curious to see what it did with a bogus date ... `DateSerial(2012,2,31)` ... looked like its response could be useful.  :-)

Comment: @HansUp Absolutely, that is something i'll not forget in the future. Out of curiosity, which question was this... if you can still remember how to find it lol?

Comment: @MattDonnan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502802/cdate-type-mismatch-error/10503155

Comment: @HansUp ^_^ Brian beat me to the answer on that occasion

Comment: Thanks Hans... this is what I went with in the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
' *********************************************************************
' FUNCTION: CJulian2Date()
'
' PURPOSE: Convert a Julian day to a date. The function works with
'          dates based on the Gregorian (modern) calendar.
'
' ARGUMENTS:
'    JulDay: The ordinal day of a year. Between 1 and 365 for all
'            years, or between 1 and 366 for leap years.
'
'    YYYY: A three or four digit integer for a year that is within the
'          range of valid Microsoft Access dates. If YYYY is omitted,
'          then YYYY is assumed to be the year of the current system
'          date.
'
' RETURNS: A date for a valid Microsoft Access year and Julian day,
'          or a Null value for an invalid Julian Day.
' *********************************************************************

Function CJulian2Date (JulDay As Integer, Optional YYYY)
    If IsMissing(YYYY) Then YYYY = Year(Date)
    If Not IsNumeric(YYYY) Or YYYY \ 1 <> YYYY Or YYYY < 100 Or YYYY _
      > 9999 Then Exit Function
    If JulDay > 0 And JulDay < 366 Or JulDay = 366 And _
      YYYY Mod 4 = 0 And YYYY Mod 100 <> 0 Or YYYY Mod 400 = 0 Then _
        CJulian2Date = Format(DateSerial(YYYY, 1, JulDay), "m/d/yyyy")
End Function
```

Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209922

Answer (score 0):

Take the year and convert to Jan 1 of that year. Add the number of days to that and convert to a date format. You could put this in a query.

> CalcDate: CDate(CLng(CDate("01/01/" & [Year]))+[day]-1)

Comment: I don't understand why you used `CDate()` twice and `CLng()` instead of `CDate("01/01/" & [YEAR]) + [DAY_NUMBER] -1`

Comment: @HansUp - I was building the pieces of this and testing as I went along and forgot an integer will be treated as days and can be added to a date and still get a date in Access. The CLng() aided in knowing I was getting the number of days.